# Choosing table from the right owner in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am quite new to SQL, and my first "job" is to get something out of an Oracle SQL database.

Just to see what's actually found in my connection I use the following:

```
SELECT owner, table_name FROM dba_tables
```

This gives me a bunch of tuples with an `owner` name and `table_name`. However, some table names are the same for different owners.

So when I run a command like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTableName
```

How do I ensure that this table is coming from owner1 and not owner2, where both of them actually have a table called `MyTableName` ?

Comment: Add `WHERE owner = 'owner1'` to you query,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT * FROM <owner>.MyTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify exactly which table with

```
select * from some_owner.my_table;
```

If you do this:

```
select * from my_table;
```

You will be selecting from the version of MY_TABLE that belongs to the owner/user with which you you are connected to the database.  So, if you connected as user SCOTT, then

```
select * from my_table;
```

effectively becomes

```
select * from scott.my_table;
```

Note that this behavior can be overridden by the use of synonyms.  Suppose user SCOTT has a synonym like this:

```
create synonym scott.my_table for fred.my_table;
```

Then SCOTT issues

```
select * from my_table;
```

Then oracle will check first for a synonym, and finding it will effectively transform the query to

```
select * from fred.my_table;
```

So in the end, the precedence is this.  When you reference a table without qualifying it with the owner,  oracle will look for it in this sequence:

1. is there a user synonym by that name? if so, use what it references *if the user has been granted necessary privileges*.
2. is there a *global* synonym by that name? if so, use what it references *if the user has been granted necessary privileges*.
3. does the user itself own a table by that name? if so, use that table.
4. return error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"